# Send JSON object via POST from JavaScript to Python

Tags: javascript, python, json, django, dojo

There is a client-side JavaScript and server-side Python, powered by Django. There is a data object: `foo_data = {"foo":1, "bar":2}`.

Now, I would like to send a post-request using `dojo/request/xhr`, and send `foo_data` along with another variable:

```
xhr.post(document.location.href, {
    data: {
        'is_foo': true,
        'data': foo_data
    },
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
}).then(function(text){
    console.log('The server returned: ', text);
});
```

And then read sent data in Django's `views.py` file:

```
def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    json.loads(request.body)
```

BUT, it doesn't work:

- if I ssend `foo_data`, python doesn't recognize it correctly as JSON object and can't read it using `json.loads`.
- I can't encode `foo_data` using `JSON.parse` because it is already an object!
- `request.POST` is an empty `QueryDict`
- `request.body` has string word `object` (instead of the real object)

Any ideas how to solve this?

Goal: send JSON object from JS --> Python and read it on server-side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

dojo.xhr has been deprecated, please consider using `dojo/request` more info here:

https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojo/request/xhr.html#dojo-request-xhr

For a live example of post to a server, you can look source code for this page:
https://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.8/ajax/demo/dojo-request-xhr-post.php

Here some a simple example of usage:

```
        require(dojo/request"],
            function(request){
                    // post the data to the server
                    request.post("your/server/script", {
                        // send your data here
                        data: { yourData: 1},
                        // wait 2 seconds for a response
                        timeout: 2000

                    }).then(function(response){
                        // do smt here when operation is successfully executed
                    });

            }
        );
```

Regarding your code sample in your question, you have't posted your server side code. But you could try to pass your data to the server using `JSON.stringify()`.